# Can't run my app says Unfortunately the application has stopped

Tags: javascript, android, xml, android-intent

I am making a simple app that that uses a maths trick ti read the mind of people(trick) but when I try to run it it stops and crashes and it never starts here is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 Button btnn;
 Button btn; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     btnn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start);
     btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Exit);
     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
        //  builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
    btnn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent toNextPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    two.class); 
            startActivity(toNextPage);
            MainActivity.this.finish();

        }
    }); 
}}
```

and here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to Brain Reader"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:textSize="22dp"
    android:typeface="serif"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Start"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launche"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Exit"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ex"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

so anyone please help ans thanks in advance
my log cat says

```
07-02 12:05:00.927: D/ThemeManager(18835): packageName=====com.example.brainreader
07-02 12:05:00.931: D/ThemeManager(18835): packageName=com.example.brainreader
07-02 12:05:01.043: E/AndroidRuntime(18835): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.brainreader/com.example.brainreader.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
07-02 12:05:01.043: E/AndroidRuntime(18835):    at com.example.brainreader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
07-02 12:05:01.047: W/ActivityManager(231):   Force finishing activity com.example.brainreader/.MainActivity
07-02 12:05:01.163: D/AES(231):     process : com.example.brainreader
07-02 12:05:01.163: D/AES(231):      module : com.example.brainreader v1 (1.0)
07-02 12:05:01.165: D/AEE/LIBAEE(231): shell: raise_exp(2, 18835, -1361051648, com.example.brainreader, 0x0x213dd00, 0x0x0)
07-02 12:05:01.165: E/AEE/LIBAEE(231): read_cmdline:com.example.brainreader
07-02 12:05:01.577: W/ActivityManager(231): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41f62250 com.example.brainreader/.MainActivity}
07-02 12:05:01.577: V/ActivityManager(231): Enqueueing pending finish: ActivityRecord{41f62250 com.example.brainreader/.MainActivity}
07-02 12:05:01.689: I/InputDispatcher(231): channel '41480db8 Starting com.example.brainreader (server)' ~ abortBrokenDispatchCycle - notify=false
07-02 12:05:07.434: I/ActivityManager(231): Process com.example.brainreader (pid 18835) has died.
07-02 12:05:07.434: V/ActivityManager(231): Dying app: ProcessRecord{41c57800 18835:com.example.brainreader/10095}, pid: 18835, thread: android.os.BinderProxy@418da480
07-02 12:05:07.440: V/ActivityManager(231): Removing app ProcessRecord{41c57800 0:com.example.brainreader/10095} from list [ActivityRecord{4210c030 com.android.contacts/.DialtactsContactsEntryActivity}, ActivityRecord{41455818 com.android.phone/.InCallScreen}, ActivityRecord{41691d88 com.gionee.launcher/.GNLauncherActivity}] with 3 entries
07-02 12:05:07.440: V/ActivityManager(231): Removing app ProcessRecord{41c57800 0:com.example.brainreader/10095} from list [] with 0 entries
07-02 12:05:07.440: V/ActivityManager(231): Removing app ProcessRecord{41c57800 0:com.example.brainreader/10095} from list [] with 0 entries
07-02 12:05:07.440: V/ActivityManager(231): Removing app ProcessRecord{41c57800 0:com.example.brainreader/10095} from list [] with 0 entries
07-02 12:05:07.440: V/ActivityManager(231): Removing app ProcessRecord{41c57800 0:com.example.brainreader/10095} from list [] with 0 entries
07-02 12:05:11.654: W/ActivityManager(231): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{41f62250 com.example.brainreader/.MainActivity}
```

Comment: Can you check your logcat and provide more info on the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your **ImageButton to Button** in XML file..

Or

Change **Button to ImageButton** in your Java Class

```
ImageButton btnn;
ImageButton btn; 

btnn= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Start);
btn= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Exit);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Buttons to ImageButton, instead of :

```
btnn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start);
btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Exit);
```

Use :

```
btnn= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Start);
btn= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Exit);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing this step then follow: 
Chek your Android-Manifest.xml, if you found no entry for you MainActivity then add the following:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/any_string">
</activity>
```

if it works for you.....

Answer (score 0):

You are casting ImageButton to a Button type. Its wrong what ur doing.
should be ImageButton type.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your Button to ImageButton in your code.